# Access list using LINQ in SharePoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-list

I am going to access SharePoint list using LINQ and load to grid. I have Employees and Projects lists in share point site.

I've found some code [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/156014/How-to-use-LINQ-to-Sharepoint.aspx)

```
private void BindGrid()
        {
            SPLinqDataContext dc = new SPLinqDataContext(SPContext.Current.Web.Url);
            EntityList<EmployeesItem> Employees = dc.GetList<EmployeesItem>("Employees");

            var EmployeeQuery = from e in Employees.ToList()
                                select new
                                {
                                    e.Title,
                                    e.FirstName,
                                    Position = e.Position.Title,
                                    PositionDescription = e.Position.Description,
                                    Department = e.Position.Department.Title
                                };
            GridView1.DataSource = EmployeeQuery;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
```

My problem is regarding `<EmployeesItem>`. Is this inherits with my reference? or should I suppose to create a separate class in .net as we normally do?

note - I mean reference is:
We should generate the LINQ to SharePoint proxy code in order to use LINQ. 
`spmetal.exe /web:http://localhost/sites/MySampleWebSite /namespace:AccessSPDatawithLINQ.VisualWebPart1 /code:SPLinq.cs`

Comment: Can you elaborate on your problem? What do you have _reference_ issue with `<EmployeesItem>`?

Comment: Edited. :) I want to know that this <EmployeeItem> is gain from my sharepoint site list or Should I suppose to create a class in .net? Consider me as a very new to Sharepoint plz. :)

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding

**Point 1**: You will execute your LINQ query and you will read complete SPList `Employees` from sharepoint to `List<EmployeesItem>` in memory. *Now I don't know if you modify these `EmployeesItem`, will that reflect in your SP list? You can test this yourself.*

**Point 2**: Here you are creating a [Anonymous](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) type. If you modify this object, it will not modify your `EmployeesItem` object.

**Point 3**: Here you have in memory query, which has `IEnumerable` of Anonymous type. Unless and until you evaluate this `IEnumerable` (by doing `.ToList()`), your `EmployeeQuery` will not execute. As of now, according to your code, when you do `.DataBind()`; your `EmployeeQuery` will execute.

```
private void BindGrid()
{
   SPLinqDataContext dc = new SPLinqDataContext(SPContext.Current.Web.Url);
   EntityList<EmployeesItem> Employees = dc.GetList<EmployeesItem>("Employees");

   var EmployeeQuery = from e in Employees.ToList() //Point 1
                       select new                   //Point 2
                       {
                           Title = e.Title,
                           FirstName = e.FirstName,
                           Position = e.Position.Title,
                           PositionDescription = e.Position.Description,
                           Department = e.Position.Department.Title
                       };
   GridView1.DataSource = EmployeeQuery;            //Point 3
   GridView1.DataBind();
```

}

Hope this helps.